# Xcode - How to profile an application as root?

Tags: xcode, macos, root, profiler, xcode-scheme

Xcode will allow me to run my application as root (the "Debug Process As" option in the scheme allows you to select "Me" or "root"). How can I run it through the profiler as root?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: I don't think you can, unless you run `Instruments` as root (i.e. `sudo open /Path/To/Instruments.app`) and attach to the process.

Comment: Thanks; running Instruments as root worked. (I had to do `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments` instead of `open` though)

Comment: If you found a way to to do it, it would be helpful if you write it up as an answer.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson I added an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to run Instruments as root and attach to the process.

To run Instruments as root:

```bash
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Ins‌​truments
```